# Could not find member 'supplementary_data_map' using Paypal Rest API on .NET

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using the Paypal Rest API via the .NET Paypal SDK Nuget package.

It's working for virtually all our customers and works in all our local tests. But, some customers are not able to complete checkout and we're getting this error in our logs.

> Error while deserializing JSON: Could not find member
>   'supplementary_data_map' on object of type 'Transaction'. Path
>   'transactions[0].supplementary_data_map'

Here is a fuller stack trace with some of the nested calls removed to make it a bit clearer:

```
Error while deserializing JSON: Could not find member 'supplementary_data_map' on object of type 'Transaction'. Path 'transactions[0].supplementary_data_map', line 1, position 2329.
at PayPal.Api.JsonFormatter.ErrorHandler(System.Object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs)
...
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](System.String, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)
at PayPal.Api.JsonFormatter.ConvertFromJson[T](System.String)
at PayPal.Api.PayPalResource.ConfigureAndExecute[T](PayPal.Api.APIContext, HttpMethod, System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean)
at PayPal.Api.Payment.Execute(PayPal.Api.APIContext, System.String, PayPal.Api.PaymentExecution)
at Our.ApplicationServices.Payment.PayPalRestService.GetExpressCheckoutDetails(Newitts.Core.Shopping.Order, System.String) in c:\..\ApplicationServices\Payment\PayPalRestService.cs:line 183
...
```

The deserializing erro looks like it is happening inside the API wrapper. Why is this happening and can we stop it, or deal with it?